# Is it possible to resize a floating window?

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, lua, floating-windows

As title. Say I just created a floating window and some lines of it are too long to be displayed properly(to me), then in this case I would prefer to resize that window to make it larger instead of setting the window option `set wrap`(since some lines are wrapped more than once).